# Are there any visual elements commonly associated with AI?

Tags: social

Are there any visual elements, patterns, colors, graphs, maps, or even programming fonts that are used and even recurring in artificial intelligence and machine learning processes?

As a designer, it is not entirely clear what these "look" like realistically, as most generally associate AI with the kind of colors and textures generally seen in sci-fi films.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A characteristic visual element for neural network might be the node diagram, which shows (schematically) the nodes in the layers of a neural network and the connections between the nodes, both within and between the layers, that get weighted as the network is trained.

If you do a Google search on "neural network node diagram", you will see what I mean.

You might also think of any sort of video or photo with computer-identified features highlighted, as in a Google image search for "machine vision feature detection".

If you are looking for something more concrete, you can think of racks of GPU cards, or a spinning LIDAR scanner.

Comment: I think due to a lack of sufficient imagery based on how AI realistically works, one has to go down to how it actually works. What you offered is a good starting point, thank you.